# Fitting a power law on linear and log scale

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am fitting a power law $Y = aX^b$ to a data set. There are two ways to do this:

- One is on log-scale, which means fitting $\log(Y)$ to $a_1 + b_1\log(X)$.
- In other case, using linear scale to fit $Y = a_2X^{b_2}$.

Mathematically, both should be same, with $a_1 = \log (a_2)$ and $b_1 = b_2$. However, I am getting different fitting parameters by two methods (first looking visually poor!).

Here is a working example:

```
Y = {{1., 4.69246}, {2., 61.9172}, {3., 428.652}, {4., 2687.97}, {5., 10869.6}};

nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[Log[Y], a1 + b1 x, {a1, b1}, x];
nlm1["ParameterTable"]
Show[ListPlot[Y], Plot[Exp[nlm1[Log[x]]], {x, 0.5, 6}]]

nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[Y, a2*x^b2, {a2, b2}, x];
nlm2["ParameterTable"]
Show[ListPlot[Y], Plot[nlm2[x], {x, 0.5, 6}]]
```

Comment: Mathematically, these two procedures are not the same (even though they make look like at first sight) because you make different assumptions about the errors. See for example: [Physics SE: Power fit to some experimental data](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/115088/power-fit-to-some-experimental-data) or [CrossValidated SE: Regression for power law](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243184/regression-for-power-law).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is in the way you treat the residuals. The real model is usually:

```
Y == a X^b + error
```

where `error` follows some distribution (usually assumed to be a normal distribution).

When you log both sides, you get:

```
Log[Y] == Log[a X^b + error]
```

Note how you can't actually simplify the log on the right any more because of the + under the Log. (**edit** note also how there is no guarantee that `a X^b + error` is actually positive, so it's not even clear you're allowed to take the log at all!)

However, NonLinearModelFit implicitly assumes a model of the form `y == f[x] + error`, so the two formulations aren't equivalent.

Of course, you could start from the other side and assume that the real model is:

```
Log[Y] == Log[a X^b] + error == Log[a] + b Log[X] + error
```

This formulation is often very useful or even preferable over the previous one (many physical phenomena play out on log scales rather than linear scales), but then the corresponding model in normal space would be:

```
Y == Exp[error] * (a X^b)
```

Again: when you assume an additive error model one way, you will end up with a non-additive error model on the other side. That's why these two models don't fit in the same way.

My rule of thumb is: if you can find a simple transformation (log-log, log-linear, linear-log etc.) that makes your data linear, you should probably go with that. There's usually a good justification for it and it's a lot easier to judge the quality of your fit when it's just a straight line.

Comment: +1 for explaining different ways that error might be incorporated.  It is my biased option that some folks at this site forget (and even seem unaware) that the error structure is an essential component of a "model".  The next step (which I know practice) is the examination of residuals for any deviations from a proposed error structure.  But with so few observations here, only very gross departures can be observed.

Comment: `Log[a X^b]` expands to `Log[a] + b Log[X]` rather than `Log[a] * b Log[X]`, unless I missed something. Your overall point still stands of course.

Comment: thanks for an elaborative explanation. I get your point. However, the data I provided, gives a better fit for a*x^b, rather than a + b*Log(x) (which makes data linear !!)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: @user49535 I don't know if I agree with you. The fit `LinearModelFit[Log[Y], {1, x}, x]` is not perfect, but neither is `NonlinearModelFit[Y, a x^b, {a, b}, x]`, which has significantly greater residuals for the 2nd and 3rd data points than the others.

Comment: @user49535 "gives a better fit for ax^b".  Are saying that what looks good to you is the yardstick to judge the quality of a fit?  While there are very few data points in your example (and asking data to fit 3 parameters - $a$, $b$, and $\sigma^2$ with just 5 data points is a bit extreme), there are more objective measures such as AIC to rank the quality of the fits.  Does the "real" set of data have more data points?

Answer (score 2):

Log[Y! will not only logarithmize the function value, but also the argument.

If you fit the logarithms,  the errors are equally distributed. However, if you then take the exponent, the first points will have small errors and the last points large errors. This is clearly visible in:

```
Y = {{1., 4.69246}, {2., 61.9172}, {3., 428.652}, {4., 2687.97}, {5., 
    10869.6}};
Ylog = {#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ Y;
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[Ylog, a1 + b1 x, {a1, b1}, x];
nlm1["ParameterTable"]
Show[ListPlot[Y], Plot[Exp[nlm1[x]], {x, 0.5, 6}]]
```

[image]